# Integral sign with circle (AND arrow on the circle) through it

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, notation

I know from multivariable calculus that the integral sign with circle in its middle means integrating along a closed path.

So when I encountered in complex analysis the above integral sign *but with an arrow on the circle to indicate orientation*, I automatically assumed oriented closed contour.

[image]

But now on reading my textbook carefully, it only says that the arrowed circle actually means oriented contour (and doesn't say anything about whether the contour is necessarily closed).

So what does the arrowed circle really mean? Can it really also refer to a smooth oriented arc (i.e. *not* a closed curve)?

Comment: Any notation is used however the author chooses to use it.  Of course is *can* mean a non-closed curve.  I would not use it that way, but so far Congress has not outlawed that use!

Comment: An "Urphaenomen" of geometry is the fact that for any reasonable domain $B$ one has $\partial\partial B=0$, i.e. that the boundary (or "contour") $\partial B$ is "closed". An example: The boundary of a full torus $B$ in ${\mathbb R}^3$ is a "closed" two-dimensional surface, the latter having no boundary. – In particular, the "contour" of a domain in ${\mathbb R}^2$ is automatically closed.

Comment: @GEdgar You've got a point. I was asking about conventional usage of course.

Answer (score 2):

I bet your text defines a contour as a closed curve. :)

Comment: It does not. It separately defines a loop as closed contour.

Comment: Fair enough. The closed loop in the integral has to refer to a closed loop, so something is amiss with your text. Not to mention that "counterclockwise" on a general path requires some liberties to define. What's the text?

Comment: The authors are Saff & Snider. The explanation for the notation is given in a short footnote; they did not formally introduce it, but they did state that indicated contour is positively oriented. It's actually a not-bad text, once I got past the fact that it's an engineering (i.e. not math) textbook and the jumpy  organisation of topics in the middle section.

Comment: Coincidentally, I looked at Saff and Snider in my office a few hours ago. They have already told you that the circle denotes a closed loop. They are just adding — yes, in a footnote — the comment that the arrow indicates the orientation on the closed loop.

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty sure the circle-means-closed-contour wasn't explicitly introduced. You could infer it, but not with certainty, and thus my uncertainty haha.